# jquery selector help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

Is it possible to use AND operator in jquery selector?  My requirement is, I have a hidden input field inside an li tag.  This li will be hidden based on some operation.  In another button click I need to find out values of hidden input which are inside li and li tag style is not equal to hidden.

To do this i am doing

```
$(":input[class^=StoreID]").each(function (k) {
    if ($(this).parent().attr("style") != "display: none;") {
        storeID[k] = $(this).attr("value");
    }
});
```

Can this be modified in the selector itself?

```
$(":input[class^=StoreID]").parent().not('.hidden').each(function(k){.......etc});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This should work...

```
$('li:visible :input[class^=StoreID]').attr("value");
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine now .didt know about visible selector before.